# Run AWS CLI from java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I'm trying to run AWS CLI commands directly from java code.

The reason for that is because AWS Java SDK does not allow to create redirects and I need to create a redirect somehow from a Java application.

So far my code looks as follows:

```
private String runAwsCli(String cliCommand) {

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cliCommand);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();

        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
            return IOUtils.toString(bufferedReader);
        }
}
```

However, when this method is invoked I get:

```
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
```

I would really appreciate any help,

Thanks!

Comment: What are you passing to this method?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `aws elbv2 create-rule --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:451196421521:listener/app/ECS-ALB-development/2hdhj3jb4chg1ddba/1cbhd8d49e5h416x --priority 10 --conditions Field=path-pattern,Values='/chocolate' --actions Type=redirect,RedirectConfig={Protocol=HTTP,Port=80,Host=10.33.33.333,Path=/oats,StatusCode=HTTP_302}`

Comment: Anything that you can do with the CLI you can do with a _recent_ SDK, for the simple reason that the CLI is built using the SDK. I suspect that you have an older SDK, because [the docs say that you redirect actions are supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticloadbalancingv2/model/RedirectActionConfig.html)

Comment: @kdgregory Thanks, can you add my answer? I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dozens of tries to run `awc cli` command from Java I did not succeed and decided to switch to aws sdk.

So the code that creates a redirect looks like:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancingv2.AmazonElasticLoadBalancing;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancingv2.model.*;




            AmazonElasticLoadBalancing amazonElasticLoadBalancing = AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClientBuilder.defaultClient();
            CreateRuleRequest createRuleRequest = new CreateRuleRequest();
            createRuleRequest.setListenerArn(LISTENER_ARN);
            createRuleRequest.setPriority(priority);
            Action action = new Action();
            action.setType(REDIRECT);

            RuleCondition ruleCondition = new RuleCondition();
            ruleCondition.setField(PATH_PATTERN);
            ruleCondition.setValues(singletonList(requestUrl));

            RedirectActionConfig redirectActionConfig = new RedirectActionConfig();
            redirectActionConfig.setHost(HOST);
            redirectActionConfig.setPort(PORT);
            redirectActionConfig.setProtocol(PROTOCOL);
            redirectActionConfig.setPath(DESTINATION_URL);
            redirectActionConfig.setStatusCode(HTTP_301);

            action.setRedirectConfig(redirectActionConfig);

            createRuleRequest.setActions(singletonList(action));
            createRuleRequest.setConditions(singletonList(ruleCondition));

            CreateRuleResult createRuleResult = amazonElasticLoadBalancing.createRule(createRuleRequest);
```